# mySQL a more elegant query matching some (not all) criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a messy solution but think that there must be a simple and more elegant method of writing this query.

Looking for matches in one table. The table has 6 columns.(maybe more later)

Rows needs to be returned if there is a match over three columns.

For example column names colour, size, shape, weight, height, width

A returned row can because the WHERE clause gets a hit on colour, height, width.
Or a hit with size, shape, width.

Basically any combination of any three columns.

I can see the solution using (size, width, height) OR (colour, shape, width) OR (colour, size, width)........ but that is just a daft way of going about it.

There must a be simple method that is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want something like this:

```
select * from table where 
(col1 = x)
+
(col2 = y)
+
(col3 = z)
+
(col4 = w)
+
(col5 = v)
>= 3
```

A boolean expression like `col1 = x` returns either `true` or `false`, `1` or `0`. Therefore this matches any row where at least 3 columns match, no matter which ones of the 5.

However on a side note, having attributes in different columns is a sign of a not so good database design. What if you need to have one more attribute for one item. You'd have to alter the whole table. All other items would have `null` in that column, wasting space. And if an item has `null` in a column, does it really have not that attribute or was it simply not set?

Consider having the attributes in rows rather than columns and read about normalization.

Comment: Hey FancyPants, thats what I have been looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: FancyPants, what is happening with the query is that I am trying to 'best guess' an end result from a users live data. Continuing with the  above example is a user is entering data on a form when a number of fields are completed/changed a suggestion is offered up a bit like a form wide autofill but different